# How to Parse a File Path to SQL Server at Runtime

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I wish to include a file path in an SQL Server query which is executed from C#. The file path is obtained from a textBox, which in turn was provided by an open file dialog. The SQL server query is contained in the following string:

```
string strSqlAcctSelect = String.Format("SELECT Code AS dhAccountType,
                                                     Name as dhAcctName 
                                           INTO {0} " + "FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0; DATABASE = 
    {1}', 'SELECT * FROM " + "[Sheet1$]')", strAcctTabName, this.textBoxAcctPath.Text);
```

Where at runtime:

```
    this.textBoxAcctPath.Text = "J:\\CCCDataVic\\RMH\\PE1006Data\\DHCC.xls";
```

When this string is parsed back to screen of course the file path string looks as it should: 'J:\CCCDataVic\RMH\PE1006Data\DHCC.xls'.

The problem is this: how do I include a string containing a path in an SQL Query in C# (as above) using the literal "\" (single back slash) without parsing the query "\" (the double back slash)?

Whatever you do, the string is parsed to SQL containing the double back slash which SQL doesn't like.

Comment: Define "which SQL doesn't like". SQL does like double-backslashes ;-))))

Comment: This is not a solution, but you can use "/" instead.

Comment: Otherwise, I'd try treating this as a verbatim string literal: 
`this.textBoxAcctPath.Text = @"J:\CCCDataVic\RMH\PE1006Data\DHCC.xls";`
This, of course, only works when the string value is specified upfront.

Comment: "SQL doesn't like" = SQL wants file paths which are seperated by single backslashes, not double backslashes. @Dawebber. Using a verbatim string does not work, as at runtime all backslashes (whether you prefix the relevent string with @ or not) are all stored as "\\".

Comment: Try doing : System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\\out.txt", this.textBoxAcctPath.Text); . In the resulting file, do you see a path with two backslashes, or one ?

Comment: @Dr. Camus: What about String.Replace("\\\\","\\"). Not very elegant, but may work. I don't think you'll be able to wrangle C# to do what you want to do otherwise.

Comment: I have tried all of this. I niavely overlooked your first post saying "use "/" instead". This indeed looks like the way to go. I have now run all my queries in SQL Management Studio and they work with "/". So the answer is to convert all strings using the Uri class as @User123343 stated below and use these "/" seperated strings, remembering to convert back for C# outputs or edits. Thanks for all your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string path = new Uri(this.textBoxAcctPath.Text).AbsolutePath;
```

But this would throw exception if you supply invalid path, so I advise you to use below code

```
string validPath = string.Empty;

if (Uri.TryCreate(this.textBoxAcctPath.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
   validPath = uri.AbsolutePath;               
}
else
{
   throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Path");
}


string strSqlAcctSelect = String.Format("SELECT Code AS dhAccountType,
                                                     Name as dhAcctName 
                                           INTO {0} " + "FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0; DATABASE = 
    {1}', 'SELECT * FROM " + "[Sheet1$]')", strAcctTabName, validPath);
```

Comment: These both work to a degree. They remove the double backslashes. However, this class replaces them with forward slashes. To combat this I attempted "string path = new Uri(this.textBoxCCTabPath.Text).LocalPath;" this again produced the dredded double backslash. Any other ideas?

Comment: This is the way to go. SQL accepts "/"s as path seperators. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood the original post correctly, you may be getting confused because of the Visual Studio Debugger. 
e.g. consider this C# code :

```
    string str = "a\\b"; 

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("string {0} has length {1}", str, str.Length));
```

This displays :  string a\b has length 3

In Visual Studio, the debugger will show the contents of str as :

```
"a\\b"
```

, but it is stored in the computer at execution time (taking a very simplified view) as "a\b".

Comment: This is not the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
string strSqlAcctSelect = String.Format("SELECT Code AS dhAccountType,
                                                     Name as dhAcctName 
                                           INTO {0} " + "FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0; DATABASE = 
    {1}', 'SELECT * FROM " + "[Sheet1$]')", strAcctTabName, this.textBoxAcctPath.Text.Replace(@"\\", @"\"));
```

Comment: This does not work as I have tried this. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: This will not work, you have to do something like below.

string path = this.textBoxAcctPath.Text.Replace(@"\\\", @"\"));

then pass this parameter 'path'